# How do I align my partition table properly?

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I am in the process of building my first RAID5 array. I've used mdadm to create the following set up:

```
root@bondigas:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Wed Oct 20 20:00:41 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5860543488 (5589.05 GiB 6001.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953514496 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Wed Oct 20 20:13:48 2010
          State : clean, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

 Rebuild Status : 1% complete

           UUID : f6dc829e:aa29b476:edd1ef19:85032322 (local to host bondigas)
         Events : 0.12

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       4       8       64        3      spare rebuilding   /dev/sde
```

While that's going I decided to format the beast with the following command:

```
root@bondigas:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/md1p1 
mke2fs 1.41.11 (14-Mar-2010)
/dev/md1p1 alignment is offset by 63488 bytes.
This may result in very poor performance, (re)-partitioning suggested.
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=16 blocks, Stripe width=48 blocks
97853440 inodes, 391394047 blocks
19569702 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=0
11945 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848

Writing inode tables: ^C 27/11945
root@bondigas:~# ^C
```

I am unsure what to do about "/dev/md1p1 alignment is offset by 63488 bytes." and how to properly partition the disks to match so I can format it properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A friend of mine pointed out that I can just mkfs.ex4 right on `/dev/md1` without partitioning anything, so I deleted the partition and did that and it appears to be formatting now.

Answer (score 18):

Since alignment pops up in a lot of places -

- "Advanced Format" hard drives with 4k blocks
- SSDs
- RAID
- LVM

- I'll expand a bit on the question.

### Aligning partitions

["Linux on 4kB-sector disks"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw074KB-Disksdth-LX) (IBM developerWorks) walks through the steps with fdisk, parted and GPT fdisk.

With fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/XXX 
c # turn off DOS compatibility
u # switch to sector units
p # print current partitions, check that start sectors are multiples of 8

# for a new partition:
n # new partition
<select primary/secondary and partition #>
first sector: 2048 
  # 2048 is default in recent fdisk, 
  # and is compatible with Vista and Win 7, 
  # 4k-sector disks and all common RAID stripe sizes
```

### Aligning the file system

This is primarily relevant for RAID (levels 0, 5 and 6; not level 1); the file system performs better if it is created with knowledge of the stripe sizes.

It can also be used for SSDs if you wish to [align the file system to the SSD erase block size](http://tytso.livejournal.com/2009/02/20/) (Theodore Tso, Linux kernel developer).

In the OP post `mkfs` apparently auto-detected the optimal settings, so no further action was required.

If you wish to verify, for **RAID** the relevant parameters are:

- block size *(file system block size, ex. 4096)*
- stripe size *(same as mdadm chunk size, ex. 64k)*
- stride: `stripe size / block size` *(ex. 64k / 4k = 16)*
- stripe-width: `stride * #-of-data-disks` *(ex. 4 disks RAID 5 is 3 data disks; 16*3 = 48)*

*From [Linux Raid Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#ext2.2C_ext3.2C_and_ext4). See also [this simple calculator](http://busybox.net/~aldot/mkfs_stride.html) for different RAID levels and number of disks.*

For **SSD erase block alignment** the parameters are:

- fs block size *(ex. 4096)*
- SSD erase block size *(ex. 128k)*
- stripe-width:  erase-block-size / fs-block-size *(ex. 128k / 4k = 32)*

*From [Theodore's SSD post](http://tytso.livejournal.com/2009/02/20/).*

### Aligning LVM extents

The potential issue is that LVM creates a 192k header. This is a multiple of 4k (so no issue with 4k-block disks) but may not be a multiple of RAID stripe size (if LVM runs on a RAID) or SSD erase block size (if LVM runs on SSD).

See [Theodore's post](http://tytso.livejournal.com/2009/02/20/) for the workaround.

Comment: @Marco How so? The first one, to IBM Developer Works, even has a benchmark graph of the write performance penalty for using unaligned partitions, and a sidebar on RAID. The blogpost by Tso on SSD alignment has moved at least twice since I wrote this. Updated the link again, but there's no guarantee it will keep working.

Comment: Alternative link on SSD: [Aligning SSD partitions](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/8397/)

Answer (score 6):

I find this way to be the easiest

```
parted -a opt /dev/md0
(parted) u MiB
(parted) rm 1
(parted) mkpart primary 1 100%
```

or an alternate dirty method would simply go like this

```
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 1 -1
```

Comment: The parted documentation suggests using MB and GB, not MiB or GiB, if one wishes to allow parted to attempt to optimise partitions automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like mkfs.ext4 wants filesystems on your RAID to start on a 64 KiB boundary.  If you use the whole disk, it starts at 0 which is of course also a multiple of 64 KiB...

Most partitioning tools nowadays will use a 1 MiB boundary by default anyway (fdisk probably doesn't).

The reason for this is that most hard disks & SSDs use fysical sectors on the device that are much bigger than the logical sectors.  The result of that is that if you read a logical sector of 512 bytes from disk, the hardware actually has to reads a much larger amount of data.

In case of your software RAID device something similar happens: data on it is stored in "chunks" of 64 KiB with the default mdadm settings.